# does the data sent to the server using http Post update the servers API url?

Tags: sql, http, flutter, post, dart

Im a newbie to flutter so please if you think the question context is wrong update it, im fetching a data from an SQl server to my flutter app, and i also want to send the users info back to the server after they fill out a form, im using the http.post and i get the response’s body correctly but when i open the Server Url (api url) i dont see it updated with the new info i posted to it, can someone please tell me how Post is supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Flutter too, this is a working example of how i understand it

```
class HttpService {
createUser(String name, String lastname) async {
    Map data = {'name': name, 'lastname': lastname};
    var body = json.encode(data);
    var jsonResponse = null;
    var response = await http.post(serverUrl + "/create/",
        headers: {
          HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: '**Token_here_if_you_use_it**',
          HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
          }, body: body);
    jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      if (jsonResponse != null) {
        print(jsonResponse.toString());
      }
    } else {
      print(jsonResponse.toString());
    }
  } 
}
```

In your main.dart :

```
final HttpService httpService = HttpService();
httpService.createUser(name,lastname);
```

Comment: Hello, this is somewhat a type of the code, that wasnt my question,

Comment: Im sayinh when i send the data as post(url, body: {“data”: “name”}) for example it doesnt show in the API that I added the name .. how do i make sure the server got The data I posted to it

Comment: @azheen What do you mean by "it doesnt show in the API" what "API" ? are you talking about your server backend ?

Comment: Yes the backend

Comment: is it a NodeJs Backend or what ? do you have some code you can post ? or are you asking how to do it ?

Comment: If i have an Api Url that opens a JsonCode such as {“tomato”: 12} and then in my app i send something to the server as http.post(ApiUrl, body: {“potatoe”: 12});,,,,, will i be able to see the potatoe in the APIUrl such as {{“tomato”: 12} {“potatoe”:10}}? Or the API doesn’t update with the post, the server Just recieves my data(i.e the potato)?

Comment: You don't see it in the API Url you see it in the req.body in a json form

Comment: How do i know the server got my data then ?

Comment: You do a try-catch in which you persist your data